# Primefaces how to change URL address

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have an application which has primefaces Commandbuttons. They use ajax to update form. What I want to do is, when user clicks some button say (button1) the address bar will change to `http://localhost:8080/myApp/button1`. I give button1 as an example it can be some custom text.Is there any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use normal [links](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) or [buttons](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/button.html) instead of command [links](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/commandLink.html) or [buttons](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/commandButton.html).

E.g.

```
<p:button value="Go to button1 page" outcome="button1" />
```

It'll open `button1.xhtml` and point to `/myApp/button1.xhtml`. To get rid of the file extension, consider [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.org/prettyfaces/) or [FacesViews](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/facesviews/ExtensionlessURLs).

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink/)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/)